# List instead of Array in varargs java method

Tags: java, arrays, list, variadic-functions

I have a varargs method in java. So, the method expects an array of `Object`s. I passed a `List` to the method and it worked! I mean, it not only compiled, but the tests were green. So, my question is - do I have to call `myList.toArray()` when calling the method, or does this call happen automatically?

Thanks in advance!

And here is the code:

```
createSomething(final Object... parameters) {
  // varargs method
}

List<Object> data = new ArrayList<Object>();

createSomething(data); // is this wrong?
createSomething(data.toArray()); // should I always do this?
```

Comment: try it and let us know

Comment: What's the type of the vararg parameter? It's `Object`. A `List` is an `Object`.

Comment: Please do everyone that is trying to help you a favour and show us the code of the method and how you call it.

Comment: Probably. Are you just calling `toString()` implicitly (or explicitly) in your varargs method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to think that the list was implicitely transformed to an array, and that the method was invoked with an array containing each element of the list.

That's not the case. In fact, the method was invoked with an array containing a single element: the list itself.

Test it with

```
private void testVarargs(Object... args) {
    System.out.println(args.length);
    System.out.println(args[0]);
}
```

and

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
testVarargs(list);
```

The result won't be

```
2 
hello
```

but

```
1
[hello, world]
```

And that's normal: you just passed a single object as argument to the method, which happens to be a List. The List is thus enclosed inside a one-length array and the method is called with that array as argument.